# Difference: prank vs mischief

Tags: meaning, word-usage

It seems that the meaning of `prank` and `mischief` are same, which is `chidlish trick`

`The boy just wants to brew mischief`

`The boy was playing a prank on us`

I want to know the difference between them? and how to use them?

Comment: With a prank, the intended “victim” is usually clear; with general mischief there may be no identified “victim”   I also think that a prank involves some level of deception whereas mischief just involves a more general upset of the status quo.

Comment: I would add, too, that "prank" usually refers to a very specific and planned joke or trick (often a practical joke) you want to play on your intended victim, while "mischief," as @Jim pointed out, does not necessarily refer to any specific behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, while they sometimes get out of hand, "pranks" are intended as jokes or to poke fun at some person or institution.  In general the intent is to cause no physical injury or significant property damage.  "Mischief" is a much more general term that includes "pranks", but also includes, eg, graffiti, vandalism, and other destructive acts.  "Pranks" may or may not be malicious, but "mischief" almost always is,

Answer (score 1):

A ***[prank](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prank)*** is an actual act, like a trick, a practical joke, a specific action meant to cause a particular result. 
***[Mischief](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mischief)*** is a broader term that usually refers to more general (socially negative) behaviour. (all references M-W)

> The pig's blood scene in *Carrie* was a truly cruel prank. People who like to pull pranks are often up to mischief of one kind or another.